# Infinite loop after scroll event

Tags: jquery, loops, scroll, infinite

I am trying to make a div to scroll only 70px every time, however I am now stuck in an infinite loop everytime I scroll.

I don't have any looping functions in my function but it somehow gives me infinite loop:

```
var currentTop = 0;    
$('.contactDiv').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    currentTop = currentTop + 70;
    $('.contactDiv').animate({
        scrollTop: currentTop
    }, 500);

    return false;
});
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: where have you intialise `currentTop`..????

Comment: inside animate() you are scrolling again . It will trigger scroll event....

Comment: ah its before the function. let me edit

Comment: Ahh yes you are right @PranavCBalan. Any advice on stopping it?

Comment: Just to mention: there is no need in `e.preventDefault();` and  `e.stopPropagation();` if you use `return false`

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for us to test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this trick : define a boolean variable `scrolling` that you set to true when you are doing the animation, test it, and set it back to false when the animation is finished :

```
var currentTop = 0;    
var scrolling = false;

$('.contactDiv').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e){ 
    if (!scrolling) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        currentTop = currentTop + 70;

        scrolling = true;
        $('.contactDiv').animate({
            scrollTop: currentTop
        }, 500, function(){
            scrolling = false;
        });

        return false;
    }
});
```

**Edit :**
If you have a scroll event fired just after the end of the animation, it will indeed loop until it reach the bottom of the `.contactDiv`. However, you can prevent this with an extra variable (here called `allowNextAnimation`) :

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4n8c6dhw/)**

```
var currentTop = 0;    
var scrolling = false;
var allowNextAnimation = true;

$('.contactDiv').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e){
    if (!scrolling && allowNextAnimation) {
        currentTop = currentTop + 70;

        scrolling = true;
        $('.contactDiv').animate({
            scrollTop: currentTop
        }, 500, function(){
            scrolling = false;
            allowNextAnimation = false;
        });

        return false;
    }
    allowNextAnimation = true;
});
```

Comment: There is however an issue : if you use the mouse wheel, it will also trigger a scroll event (at least on chrome) at the end of the `mousewheel` event... I'm looking for a clean workaround

Comment: But at the end of the `mousewheel` event `scrolling` is already set to `true`. So `scroll` event will be ignored.

Comment: a small timeout in the animation callback function would work, but it is ugly.

Comment: Both solutions (with flag and with binding-unbinding) require `setTimeout`. Let's just say this ugly workaround works. At least [in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/za70jpwk/1/).

Comment: Well, in my edit I found a simple workaround that does not make use of timeout... But it is still a pain in the... Well, whatever ! Spent too much time on this ^^

Comment: Two flags instead of flag and timeout. Well... It's indeed not much better :) But I also have spent a lot of time trying to solve it in normal way without any luck, so let it be so.

Answer (score 1):

Unbind the scroll event untill the first scroll completes its action and again bind the scroll event after scroll completion - in your case its animation completion.

Something like

```
function scrollHandler() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - ($(window).height() +300)) {

            $(window).unbind('scroll');
            $('.loading').show();
            .............
            .............
            .............
            $(window).bind('scroll', function () { scrollHandler(); });
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.